# Constraints in modulo arithmetics

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Consider four positive numbers a, b, c, d and addition modulo N.

I would like to determine the minimum number of constraints needed to express that:

1. $a + b + c = d$
2. $a + b + c$ does not wrap around the modulo N

I think I need at least 5 constraints, for instance:

1. $a \le a + b$
2. $b \le a + b$
3. $c \le d$
4. $a + b \le d$
5. $a + b + c = d$

Can I do with less that 5 constraints?

---

EDITS for clarification

1. We are operating modulo N so you can assume $a, b, c, d$ are all numbers in $[0, N-1]$. In fact, if they weren't they would be reduced to their congruent number modulo N in $[0, N-1]$
2. What the constraints are meant to be prevent is a situation like:
   $$a=80, b=80, c=30, d=90, N=100$$ where you have $a + b + c = d$ modulo N but the addition wraps around N
3. All the constraints operate modulo N, there is no access to integer arithmetics

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Any assumption that $a,b,c$ are all in $(0,n)$?

Comment: 1. $a+b+c = d$ and 2. $0\lt d\leq n-1$ and 3. $a,b,c\gt 0$ are all the conditions you need

Comment: @peterwhy I think there is. OP specified that all the numbers are positive and that they don't want $a+b×c$ to "wrap around modulo $n$"

Comment: @peterwhy You can assume they are all in (0, n)

Comment: @H.sapiensrex I don't think that 1. ++= and 2. 0<≤−1 and 3. ,,>0 is enough. Consider $a=80, b=80, c=30, d=90, n=100$.
Your conditions are all respected but $a+b+c$ wraps around $n$

Comment: But in that example, $80+80+30\neq 90$.

Comment: @H.sapiensrex Sorry if my notation is not clear, I wanted to mean that addition is modulo N, in my example modulo 100, so 190 = 90 modulo 100

Comment: It is still possible to do if you don't have access to integer arithmetic. Assuming $a, b, c \le d$, then you merely need to check that $b \le d-c$ and $a= d-c-b$. The subtraction can be done either with integer or modular arithmetic since the inequalities ensure there is no wraparound.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis there is no access to integer arithmetics, only modulo, I added that to the clarifications of the questions. Your proposal is more "expensive" than my current solution with 5 constraints, since it requires first to order a, b, c, d and then to apply 3 more constraints

Comment: Actually just $d<n$; $c \le d$; $b \le d-c$ and $a= d-c-b$ are sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check that $a+b+c\equiv d \bmod n$ without wraparound, i.e. you want to check whether $a+b+c=d$ in integer arithmetic. However, the only tools you have are arithmetic modulo $n$, and size comparison of the residues.

To start with you can assume that $d<n$ since $a,b,c,d$ can be assumed to be the standard residue class representatives, i.e. in the range $\{0,1,..,n-1\}$.

The following three constraints are necessary and sufficient to force none of the additions to cause a wraparound:
$$c\le d \\ b \le d−c \\ a=d−c−b $$
Each constraint ensures that the subtraction in the next one has no wraparound, and the final constraint is equivalent to the equality we want. It is fairly obvious how to extend this to any number of variables.